# How to test synthesizability and time characteristics of an isolated Verilog module?

Tags: fpga, verilog, lattice

How to test synthesizability and time characteristics of an isolated Verilog module which can have its own interface much wider than pins number of choosen FPGA?

Answer (score 0):

Timing characteristics can only exist after your design has been applied to a specific FPGA – an Ice40HX will have a different timing than a LatticeSC ; not even mentioning that the two of them have different logic units and the same verilog would be synthesized to two different netlists.

However, you should be able to synthesize your code for specific FPGA without placing it on an actual bitstream.

On top of that: The number of pins on the package has absolutely nothing to do with the architecture that you implement inside the FPGA. I don't know how you've got that idea.

Comment: You would have a hard time placing a design that needs 400 IO's in an FPGA with only 200 pins.

Comment: @ThePhoton that's true, but OP asked about synthesizability. And a Verilog module doesn't have IO pins – the signals are connected to those using either special Verilog IO (pseudo)modules or in a pin mapping file (haven't worked with the proprietary Lattice tools yet). You're referring to *placeability*, which comes a few steps later :)

Comment: I just tried to synthesize a project with a single Verilog module with wide parallel-to-parallel interface and synthesis has been failed due to low io number, not slice capacity. All I want is to check if my code will work on chosen FPGA at desired speed before coding a real interface modules.

Comment: That's interesting, if you didn't connect the modules in- and outputs to any pins, then the synthesis tool wouldn't even know how many you used

Comment: @MarcusMüller, remember that beginners might not know the difference between synthesis, place&route, mapping, etc. All they know is the clicked "build all" (which they might think of as "synthesize") and the tool produced an error. And if no constraints file is provided, the tool might arbitrarily try to fit the design into the chip with a more-or-less random mapping of top level module I/O's to chip IO pins (I haven't used Lattice tools enough to remember if they'll do this, but Xilinx ISE certainly will).

Comment: @ThePhoton not only ISE, Vivado still is capable of randomly assigning pins if you forget to define a pin mapping *sigh*.

Comment: @ThePhoton but your central point here is very important: synthesizing is but one step in the HDL/FPGA workflow, and OP might not be aware of that.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, I think the tool designers have the idea that people will design the FPGA logic, then build a board around that.  So the tool can assign pins "optimally" and the board designer would use those assignments. In practice every project I've worked on has done the board design first and then designed the FPGA logic  as layout is being completed and boards are being fabbed.

Comment: @ThePhoton yep. Classical purpose of cheaper FPGA definitely is to simply ignore the complexity of laying out a board for digital signals by dealing with routing in the FPGA – often, even after manufacturing the PCB.

Comment: Unfortunately we have many good resources about how to code HDL, but very few ones about how to put your code into real FPGA and make it work there. For example, Lattice tutorial starts with "blah-blah, create new project, then add your Verilog files here and constrains (!) files here". What if I just want to know what they are and how to write them?

Comment: ... then you'll probably have to read the full tutorial. As I tried to explain, a Verilog module doesn't universally map to the same netlist regardless of the technology used.